# 'NSNumber' is not convertible to 'Int' Swift

Tags: int, nsnumber

I am trying to do math to set the position of a shape node. It looks like this (Swift):
`var score: NSNumber?
score = score! + 1`

xcode 6 beta 5 run perfect, but xocde 6.1 not run, report 'NSnumer' is not convertible to 'Int'

Answer (score 6):

I realize that this is an older question, and you have probably figure this out already, but having similar issues myself recently, i figured i'd post an answer for posterity.

Swift is (as far as I know) still undergoing design changes as a programming language, and one thing I noticed is that I needed to start wrapping my int's inside the `Int()` function. So your example might need to look something like this:

```c
var score: NSNumber?
score = NSNumber(integer:score!) + 1
```

**Edit:**

To try and explain why we need to do this, I believe, is because `score` is an `NSNumber()`, which can have various numeric forms. `NSNumber(integer:score!)` re-wraps `score!` as an integer specifically, allowing us to use integers against it in math equations.